# How to measure latency of low latency c++ application

Tags: c++, performance, hpc

I need to measure message decoding latency (3 to 5 us ) of a low latency application.

I used following method,

```
1. Get time T1
2. Decode Data
3. Get time T2
4. L1 = T2 -T1
5. Store L1 in a array (size = 100000)
6. Repeat same steps for 100000 times. 
7. Print array.
8. Get the 99% and 95% presentile for the data set.
```

But i got fluctuation between each test. Can some one explain the reason for this ?
Could you suggest any alternative method for this.

*Note*: Application is tight loop (acquire 100% cpu) and Bind to  CPU via **taskset** commad

Comment: Do more samples, and get the average. On a modern multi-tasking system fluctuations are inevitable, but of course the fluctuations might also depend on how you get the times.

Comment: I used "gettimeofday" function to get time

Comment: On linux I use `clock_gettime` with a `clockid_t` of `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` as that hopefully only measures the CPU time taken by the specific process. I also make sure the test modifies some primitive variable that I then print after the timer has stopped to prevent the compiler from optimizing the test away.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways that performance metrics can be gathered either using code profilers or by using existing system calls.

NC State University has a good resource on the different types of timers and profilers that are available as well as the appropriate case for using each and some examples on their HPC website [here](http://www.ncsu.edu/hpc/Documents/sprofile.php).

Fluctuations will inevitably occur on most modern systems, certain BIOS setting related to hyper threading and frequency scaling can have a significant impact on the performance of certain applications, as can power-consumption and cooling/environmental settings.

Looking at the distribution of results as a histogram and/or fitting them to a Gaussian will also help determine how normal the distribution is and if the fluctuations are normal statistical noise or serious outliers.  Running additional tests would also be beneficial.